# How to get all the customer wishlist items in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, php, wishlist

I want to get all the product ids from wishlist in magento. I tried with below code but I am getting only one product id.

```
public function GetWishlistProductId($productId)
{
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $wishList = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer);
    $wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();

    if (count($wishListItemCollection)) {
        $arrProductIds = array();

        foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item) {
            /*@var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
            $product = $item->getProduct();
            $arrProductIds[] = $product->getId();

            foreach ($arrProductIds as $key => $val){
                if($productId == $val){
                    $pval=$val;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return($pval);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The follows should do what you are wanting but you will have to change your loop structure a little bit as when you loop through your products you will only have finish one iteration of the collection items in your original version:

```
public function GetWishlistProductId($productId)
{
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $wishList = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer);
    $wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();

    if (count($wishListItemCollection)) {
        $arrProductIds = array();

        foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item) {
            $arrProductIds[] = $item->getProductId();
        }
    }
    // Now here you can take that array and do what you want with it.        
    return $arrProductIds;
}
```

Comment: hi david still i am getting on product idArray
(
    [0] => 27
)

Comment: @ManiCoolDude does that entry in the database have more than one product id? You could also try `Mage::log($item->getProductId());` to log what and how many product ids are returned.

Comment: yeah david There is more than one product id

Comment: @ManiCoolDude could you update the code in the question to show the full loops?

Comment: check post i have updated with my code

Comment: @ManiCoolDude you only ever return one product id, and because of how you built your foreach loops it will awlays be the last one.

Comment: i tried with without if condition

Comment: @ManiCoolDude Update answer, now the function should give you an array of all product ids

Comment: No Luck it returns one product id

Comment: @ManiCoolDude please check that 1. there are more than 1 product in this wishlist in the database, 2. that they are visible for the store that this code is running under.